# C-sky CPU reverse-engineering

Tags: ida, disassembly, embedded

I am trying to RE a firmware for a TV STB, its based on a  GX3201 chip which is based on C-sky CPU (CK610M I think).

I am stuck in the following points :

- I am not able to properly identify the CPU architecture (probably MIPS).
- I am not able to properly identify the reset vector address to load the bootloader in IDA pro.

Does anyone have experience with these chips?

#### Update

- SDK and sources [Ftp server down](http://www.mmnt.net/db/0/0/218.75.120.99/tools_zhangling)
- CPU instruction set found in a header file
- [instruction set header file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_p4I0JC8J72ZGphTTUyMXE0Qk0/view?usp=sharing)

#### Update 2

Using the toolchain of the CPU and disassembling the `vectors.o` found in the lib directory gave me this :

```
00000458 <__reset_vector>: 
458:    711b lrw        r1, 0xA2A25441 
45a:    0f21 cmpne      r1, r2 
45c:    e802 bf         0x462 
45e:    1082 mfcr       r2, ss2 
460:    1093 mfcr       r3, ss3 
00000462 <skip_SS_ATAG>: 
462:    0f21 cmpne      r1, r2 
464:    e003 bt         0x46c 
466:    7218 lrw        r2, 0x0 // from address pool at 0x4c8 
468:    35f3 bseti      r3, r3, 31 
46a:    9302 st r3, (r2, 0)
```

#### `objdump -i` Output :

```
elf32-csky-big
 (header big endian, data big endian)
  csky
elf32-csky-little
 (header little endian, data little endian)
  csky
elf32-little
 (header little endian, data little endian)
  csky
elf32-big
 (header big endian, data big endian)
  csky
srec
 (header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  csky
symbolsrec
 (header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  csky
verilog
 (header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  csky
tekhex
 (header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  csky
binary
 (header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  csky
ihex
 (header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  csky

 elf32-csky-big elf32-csky-little elf32-little elf32-big srec 
 csky elf32-csky-big elf32-csky-little elf32-little elf32-big srec   

 symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary ihex csky symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary ihex
```

Comment: Too little info. What's the STB model/manufacturer? Firmware downloads? Do they provide GPL sources? binwalk output?

Comment: STB info : 6605-dvbs2 CHIp =GX3201 CPU family=CSLY the chip is manifactured by http://www.nationalchip.com/en/

Comment: i have found the trace of source code for the same device at this link [link](http://www.mmnt.net/db/0/0/218.75.120.99/tools_zhangling)   but the  ftp server is down at the moment.   the only thing that i have is cksy toolchain for ecos operating system i have found a header file ck_opcodes.h with mips like instruction set am trying to write radar2 plugin with the opcodes in this file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure r2 already supports MIPS, why are you writing a plugin?

Comment: When i run binwalk against the lib files of the csky-ecos toolchain i get this.          ELF, 32-bit LSB relocatable, Motorola RCE, version 1 (SYSV)   binwalk -A outputs nothing....!

Answer (score 5):

<strike>It seems very likely that this chip is indeed MIPS, so any MIPS disassembler should work. Remember to try both little-endian and big-endian variants. For finding the entrypoint, see here: [Reverse Engineering MIPS Bootloader](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11096/)</strike>

Note that it may be possible that the firmware is packed or encrypted (check binwalk's entropy analysis); in that case reading it directly from the flash chip may be necessary.

**EDIT**: So, apparently the code is *not* MIPS after all. Going by the objdump output, the instruction set seems to be a derivative of the Motorola/Freescale MCORE (previously Motorola RCE), even if they call it "csky". You should be able to disassemble raw binary by specifying binary file format and architecture to objdump, e.g.:

```
objdump -D -b binary -m csky file.bin
```

In case you don't get good results, try adding `-EB` or `-EL` to force big-endian or little-endian disassembly. Note that sometimes you may get nonsense disassembly in case there is data intermixed with code (`-D` forces disassembly of the whole file).

**EDIT2**:  C-sky support has been added to official binutils source tree. [The commit](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commitdiff;h=b8891f8d622a31306062065813fc278d8a94fe21) message says:

> V1 is derived from the MCore architecture while V2 is substantially
> different, with mixed 16- and 32-bit instructions, a larger register
> set, a different (but overlapping) ABI, etc.

**EDIT3**: C-SKY and Motorola MCore architecture support [was added](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2/pull/11448) in Radare2 reverse engineering framework. You can use it with `-a mcore` radare2 switch, also it should recognize the architecture in the ELF file directly.

Comment: thank you for the hints, the bootloader is not packed, i can see all the strings,  i found the complete toolchain with the cross compilers, how can this help me ?

Comment: if the toolchain has objdump, try using it to disassemble the firmware.

Comment: I cant disassemble directly the firmware with objdump (unknown file format) but disassembling the vectors.o in the lib directory gave me this :  '00000458 <__reset_vector>:
 458: 711b       lrw r1, 0xA2A25441
 45a: 0f21       cmpne r1, r2
 45c: e802       bf 0x462
 45e: 1082       mfcr r2, ss2
 460: 1093       mfcr r3, ss3

00000462 <skip_SS_ATAG>:
 462: 0f21       cmpne r1, r2
 464: e003       bt 0x46c
 466: 7218       lrw r2, 0x0 // from address pool at 0x4c8
 468: 35f3       bseti r3, r3, 31
 46a: 9302       st r3, (r2, 0)'

Comment: @Steavebba please add this info to the question, as well as output of "objdump -i"

Comment: dose the BF instruction  belong to the MIPS instruction set, i can find it in the M-CORE doc **a branch instruction (BR, BT, BF) that has a
backwards branch distance between 4 and 64
instructions must be detected. This short backwards
branch instruction is called the sbb.**

Answer (score 4):

To clarify this thread:

C-Sky CPU's are a 16/32 bit variable length instruction set ISA in SoC & PoC packages, that appear to be MIPS-like, that can be switched to execute code in big or little endian. The CK610M is a v1 ISA, which has the MMU, so it is able to run Linux, which contains support as of v4.19.

There are currently (since October 2018) a $6US C-Sky Development SBC's supporting the CK610M in the gx6605s SoC package produced by NationalChip. QEMU supports boot C-SKY v1 & v2 ISA.

https://c-sky.github.io/docs/gx6605s.html